# Find Create Date of files from script generated file. hadoop/hdfs

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, awk, hdfs

## I have a CMD outputs like below

```
hdfs fsck /data -files -blocks -locations -openforwrite

/data/prod/encrypt/fin1/dt=202203/FlumeData.1647955937413.tmp 378 bytes, replicated: repli                                                        cation=3, 1 block(s):  OK OPENFORWRITE
 - BP-16266705-1.1.1.1-1481807115:blk_1141513_67850462 len=378 Live_repl=3  [DatanodeInfoWithSto                                                        rage[1.1.1.1:9866,DS-b6ff1d67-d842-49cb-8d3a-cd185bc03,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[1.1.1.1                                                        0:9866,DS-f69ec6eb-5884-4ab1-a583-5640336dd41d,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[1.1.1.1:9866,DS-16f08976-40ab-b369-dbdc0a268611,DISK]]
```

From thousands of std output I'm only interested in files with OPENFORWRITE tag thus I run the below command.

```
hdfs fsck /data -files -blocks -locations -openforwrite |grep -i openforwrite

/data/prod/encrypt/fin1/dt=202203/FlumeData.1647955937413.tmp 20075 bytes, replicated: replication=3, 1 block(s), OPENFORWRITE:  OK
/data/prod/encrypt/fin1/dt=202203/FlumeData.1647955937413.tmp 20075 bytes, replicated: replication=3, 1 block(s), OPENFORWRITE:  OK
/data/prod/encrypt/fin1/dt=202203/FlumeData.1647955937413.tmp 20075 bytes, replicated: replication=3, 1 block(s), OPENFORWRITE:  OK
```

Now from the above output I  need to find/delete the file which are 7 days old, I thought it should be simple so I ran my command as below but it's not able to get the date or date diff.

```
hdfs dfs -ls |
grep OPENFORWRITE |
cut  -d " " -f1 |
awk '
    BEGIN{ MIN=10080; LAST=60*MIN; "date +%s" | getline NOW }
    {
        cmd="date -d'\''"$1" "$2"'\'' +%s"; cmd | getline WHEN;
        DIFF=NOW-WHEN; if(DIFF < LAST){ print $3 } 
   }
'

date: invalid date '/data/prod/encrypt/fin1/dt=202203/FlumeData.1647955937413.tmp'
```

How can I resolve this.
Thanks
MK

Comment: I did my best to format the code and text blocks in your question legibly but please take a look and correct any remaining issues.

Comment: Can you please explain what your awk command is trying to do? As the error shows, you're providing a filename to it, not a valid date format

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to read list of lines into lines Array using `readarray` command.

Then scan each file in a line via `find` command. Filtering with `-mtime 7`

Note the differece: `-mtime 7` file modified exactly 7 days ago.

`-mtime +7` file modified more than 7 days ago.

`-mtime -7` file modified less than 7 days ago.

Note filters can combine time ranges logic filters: For example to filter a file that is 4-5 days old

`-mtime -6 -and -mtime +4`

#### Suggesting:

```
readarray -t linesArr <<< $(hdfs fsck /data -files -blocks -locations -openforwrite |grep -i openforwrite)
for line in ${linesArr[@]}; do 
   currFile=$(echo $line| awk '{print $1}')
   if [[ $(find $currFile -mtime 7) ]]; then
      echo "$line"
   fi
done
```